# Moving files from log servers to Oracle - Flume

Tags: oracle, flume, logfiles, flume-ng

I'm trying to create a log file from the log servers and pushing it in to oracle. Is there a way I could implement the same using Flume (without HDFS setup) to push the log file in to ORACLE? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a custom sink in order to persist data into Oracle. This is relatively easy, you only have to extend the [`AbstrackSink`](http://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.5.0/apidocs/org/apache/flume/sink/AbstractSink.html) class and implement the `process()` method (basically, take an event from the channel and use the Oracle API in order to persist the data).